# pop up window not appering in asp.net web application using AjaxToolKit:PopUpExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

work i have done so far is below and i tried all the example available on stack overflow **Note:** i am trying to trigger pop-up when an area of image map will be clicked

**ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender**

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="PropertyViewModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="AreasOfMapMasterPlan"
  PopupControlID="pnlPopUpPropertyView"
  CancelControlID="btnCancelPopUpViewProperty"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

**asp:ImageMap when area over the map will be clicked the pop-up panel will have to   appear which currently not appearing**

```
<asp:ImageMap ID="AreasOfMapMasterPlan" OnClick="AreasOfMapMasterPlan_Click" runat="server"></asp:ImageMap>
```

**Pop-Up Panel**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUpPropertyView" runat="server" CssClass="modal" TabIndex="-1" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;vertical-align:middle;align-content:center;width:70%;height:400px;overflow:auto;">
  <div class="model-dialog modal-sm"></div>
  <div class="modal-content"></div>
  <div class="modal-header">
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4></div>
<div class="model-body">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Enabled="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <asp:Button ID="btnCancelPopUpViewProperty" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
  </div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a LinkButton after the Panel

```
....
   </div>
 </asp:Panel>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server"  CssClass="hidden" />
```

in your ModalPopupExtender change the TargetControlID to "LinkFake"

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="PropertyViewModalPopupExtender" 
runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkFake" PopupControlID="pnlPopUpPropertyView"
```

The Linkbutton could be hide by a CSS
In your codebehind show the panel with

```
 ...
 PropertyViewModalPopupExtender.Show()
 ....
```